# Python Bs4 - Web scraping delay

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python bs4 to make a weather condition.

I am taking the degree and day infos from html but they don't match with what is written on the interface.

Why is that happening or how can I solve this "delay" problem?

note: weather condition site is current.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



link = "https://yandex.com.tr/hava/duzce?via=hnav"



response = requests.get(link) ## 200

print(response)


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")  


degree = soup.find("div",class_ = "forecast-briefly__name")

print(degree.text)
```

It was supposed to be 28 degrees but I am returning 14 degrees. It doesn't match...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change tag selector to find the right tag. Here is an example how you can select all days and their night/day temperature:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://yandex.com.tr/hava/duzce?via=hnav"
response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for f in soup.select(".forecast-briefly__days li"):
    name = f.select_one(".forecast-briefly__name").text
    day = f.select_one(".forecast-briefly__temp_day").get_text(
        strip=True, separator=" "
    )
    night = f.select_one(".forecast-briefly__temp_night").get_text(
        strip=True, separator=" "
    )
    print(f"{name:<10} {day:>10}° {night:>10}°")
```

Prints:

```
Dün                29°         14°
Bugün       gündüz 28°    gece 13°
Sa                 26°         13°
Ça                 27°         15°
Pe                 26°         16°
Cu                 27°         17°
Ct                 24°         14°
Pa                 24°         15°
Pt                 22°         14°
Sa                 22°         11°
Ça                 20°         14°
Pe                 19°         12°
Cu                 18°         12°
Ct                 17°         10°
Pa                 16°         11°
Pt                 14°          9°
Sa                 15°          9°
Ça                 14°          9°
Pe                 17°         11°
Cu                 14°          8°
Ct                  8°          3°
Pa                 11°          7°
Pt                 12°          9°
Sa                 12°          9°
Ça                 10°          7°
Pe                  8°          6°
Cu                 12°          8°
Ct                 13°         10°
Pa                 14°          9°
Pt                 12°          7°
Sa                 12°          4°
```